# CSS transform: scale overlaps padding of container div

Tags: css, webkit, scale, overlapping

I have a grid of images with padding to the right and to the top. I added animation to scale the images a bit when hovering them with the mouse. Issue is that when the image scales it overlaps the padding mention above. I managed to solve it by using margin instead of padding but this html is from my wordpress theme and using margins instead of padding causes other issues I can't deal with.

Is there a way to achieve such behaviour with padding?

Thanks!
Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/thimim/h6pvusau/

HTML:

```
 <div class="fs_grid_gallery">

<div class="grid-gallery-item">
    <img src="http://propixelpanama.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/azrieli-1-540x375.jpg" alt="" class="fw_featured_image">
</div>

<div class="grid-gallery-item">
    <img src="http://propixelpanama.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/azrieli-1-540x375.jpg" alt="" class="fw_featured_image">
</div>

<div class="grid-gallery-item">
    <img src="http://propixelpanama.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/azrieli-1-540x375.jpg" alt="" class="fw_featured_image">
</div>

<div class="grid-gallery-item">
    <img src="http://propixelpanama.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/azrieli-1-540x375.jpg" alt="" class="fw_featured_image">
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-gallery-item
{
    width: 25%;
    padding-right:5px; 
    padding-top:5px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

img
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.fs_grid_gallery
{
    padding-bottom:5px; 
    padding-left:5px;
    width: 100%;
}


div.grid-gallery-item, div.grid-gallery-item a, .gallery_item_wrapper
{
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img.fw_featured_image
{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
}

div.grid-gallery-item:hover .fw_featured_image
{   
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);     
}
```

Comment: so when the image scales you expect the other images to get pushed to the right?

Comment: What are the "other issues" with margin?

Comment: How about removing padding from '.grid-gallery-item' and setting '5px solid white' for border-bottom and border-right?

Comment: @cocoa I expect it to clip on the content border

Comment: @makshh each grid-gallery-item is 25% width so 4 image can fit into one line, when using margin i have to calculate the size of image with javascript since margins aren't taken into the width property.

Comment: @BrunoKos Brilliant! It worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: You could also use CSS `box-sizing` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing to make sure padding and border don't affect the CSS box model